# Дата в формате UTC

Tags: php

Как получить дату в формате UTC (Y-m-d G:i:s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// установка временной зоны по умолчанию. Доступно начиная с версии PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


// выведет примерно следующее: Monday
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
```

[ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: А установка временной зоны действует на все PHP-скрипты? То есть, по идее, я мог бы написать эту строку в файле шаблона?

Comment: да конечно, если написать в начале, должно работать везде. действует в одной сесии

Answer (score 1):

Для текущего скрипта

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

...
?>
```

Если сделать для всех php скриптов на сервере
Указываем в файле конфигурации php.ini

```
date.timezone="UTC"
```

Comment: Тогда еще такой вопрос. На сервере дата записана в формате UTC. На компьютере ставлю часовой пояс (+5) и пишу сообщение. В базу данных заносится правильная дата, а при считывании (при отображении даты добавления сообщения на сайте) пишется серверное время (+3). Если же после считывания обрабатываю объектом `DateTime()` (получаю, сколько минут назад было написано сообщение), то при любом часовом поясе на компьютере пишется "1 мин. назад", то есть, указывается дата с учетом времени на моем компьютере. Почему так?

Comment: Я попробовала бы тебе помочь но этой информации мало, нужно посмотреть часовой пояс php.ini, часовой пояс mysql, часовой пояс сервера(системное время) и часовой пояс на твоём компьютере. И самое главное, что ты хочешь получить в результате :)

Comment: В результате хотелось бы получить, чтобы человек, написавший сообщение на сайте, видел под ним то же время, что и на своем компьютере... Хотя, вот, если так подумать, получается, что один напишет в 23.50 по своему времени, а другой - в 22.50 по своему, и сообщение, написанное в 22.50 будет располагаться позже написанного в 23.50. Тогда получается, что время должно выводиться в серверном часовом поясе, неважно, кто написал сообщение? То есть, я, теоретически, могу написать его в 23.50, а потом увидеть дату 22.50?

Comment: Значит давай сделаем так. Верни все настройки php.ini ко времени которое было и убери из скрипта `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`. Далее. Добавь на сайт js кусочек который при отсутствии Cookie['timeOffset'] сделает ajax запрос к странице timeOffset.php в котором передаст `var t = new Date(); $.post('/timeOffset.php', {'date':t.getDate(), 'hours': t.getHours(), 'minutes': t.getMinutes()});` Сервер получит это значение и сверит со своим временем. После сверки разницу переведёт в секунды(положительные или отрицательные) и сохранит в куку timeOffset

Comment: Далее при каждом выводе времени будет преобразовывать дату и время сохранённые на сервере в секунды, суммировать со значением куки timeOffset и полученный результат преобразовывать обратно в дату и время но уже часового пояса пользователя. **важно:** Если куки ещё нет, делать `<?php $_COOKIE['timeOffset'] = 0; ?>`. С секундами всегда выполнять именно сумму, не надо проверять на положительное или отрицательное. Просто суммируй так как если SEC = -1; TIME-SEC != TIME+SEC;

Comment: Спасибо за терпение. Но вообще, правильным было бы такое решение? Не получится ли так, как было описано выше, что сообщения, будут следовать друг за другом, а даты у них будут перемешаны? То есть, я написал в 22.00 по своему времени, а следом за мной - другой человек в 21.00 по своему. Получается, что написал он позже, а дата у него отображается раньше моей.

Comment: Ааа.. Понял. То есть, получится, что для каждого пользователя все даты будут переводиться в его отображение?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Сообщения будут выводиться в порядке даты сохранённой на сервере. Если сообщение поступит на сервер раньше, то и дата на сервере будет более ранней. И при сортировке оно выведется раньше. Путаницы не возникнет, порядок будет сохранён.